# Facebook Messenger API: Trouble setting up a webhook

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, webhooks, facebook-messenger

I am trying to set up a web hook for the new Facebook Messenger bot platform on my PHP webserver and am receiving this error:

> The URL couldn't be validated. Response does not match challenge,
>   expected value = '364011207', received='

### Resources

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/quickstart

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference#common_format

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: _“I have created a .html file on the server”_ – and that’s the problem. Why do you think the error message says it received `<html> <header> …`, but expected something completely different? The challenge value is the _only_ thing your URL is supposed to return; not an HTML document …

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I came across a fix. I scrapped my js attempt and created a new php file with the following code:

```
<?php

$challenge = $_REQUEST['hub_challenge'];
$verify_token = $_REQUEST['hub_verify_token'];

if ($verify_token === 'my_token_code') {
echo $challenge;
}
```

I got this code from the first 10 minutes of this video:
https://www.facebook.com/marketingdevelopers/videos/883648801749520/

Comment: Thank you for this! I was going nuts trying to get FB's example code to work. This is much easier.

Comment: What you did wrong was try and use NodeJS code in-line on your page. Facebook will look in the response body for the token. In NodeJS, res.send is being used to set the content of the response body - but your page is already doing that as its just a normal HTML page.

Comment: Even though this will work, it doesn't tell what you should do to make your Node.js code work... Have a look at the other answers.

Comment: @thebluefox and Jamund's answer below explained the difference between JS scripts in normal HTML pages and NodeJS server-sided scripts. If you're not using a node-js, then the abovementioned answer will work for PHP webservers.

Comment: For us, the key was : hub.challenge, hub.verify_token and not hub_challenge hub_verify_token.

Comment: What value should we use for our verify token? Is this a password for something?

Answer (score 6):

That code is **node.js** code and should be run on the server not in a `<script>` tag in your HTML.

Here's a simple walk through of setting up the messenger bot with node.js:
https://github.com/voronianski/simon-le-bottle

Essentially you need to make sure you have a host that supports node.js applications and run it as such. It will not work inside of HTML.

Answer (score 5):

If you're running this as a `Node.js` application, and you're coming from the [The Facebook Quickstart Guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/quickstart) mentioned in the question, you'll have to point the webhook URL to `[your-server-root]/webhook`. Notice this part of [the tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/getting-started/webhook-setup):

```
// Adds support for GET requests to our webhook
app.get('/webhook', (req, res) => {
    ...
    // Responds with the challenge token from the request
    res.status(200).send(challenge);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this help, but the query parameters that FB send are with underscore not dot e.g. :

- hub_verify_token
- hub_mode
- hub_challenge

P.S.

Sorry, this is valid for PHP

Comment: thanks. I ended up using php for the solution and it works

Comment: No it does use dots; not underscores. It’s PHP who replaces dots with underscores.

Answer (score 4):

I just resolved this problem by adding '/webhook' in the callback URL...

Answer (score 3):

@shane

```
webhook: function(req, res) {

   if (req.query['hub.verify_token'] === 'tokentoken') {
      res.send(req.query['hub.challenge']);
   } else {
      res.send('Error, wrong validation token');    
   }
}
```

Note sure what exactly you're doing. but this is what I did and it's working.

I've tested using ngrok server as I don't have a domain name and the callback URL is https://werwrwetwtw.ngrok.io/webhook

Hope this helps!

Comment: You see the code in the question was in a `<script>` tag and not being run on the server.

Comment: would this work on IIS? I wanna host a webhook on asp.net mvc

Comment: I have tried a similar thing. I set up an ngrok server and provided the callback URL https://mycallbackurl.ngrok.io/webhook/webhook. The "webhook" document is just a text file with your 'webhook' code from above. However, I'm still getting the same error as Shane above, where all that's being returned is the actual text content of the code, not the Challenge token. Any ideas?

Comment: @MEric I had similar issue but it has been resolved now. Please do one thing check your req.query object whether it contains 'hub.challenge' or not.
I was using restify so I added queryparser middleware and it works.