# Facebook Messenger API - Trouble setting up a webhook in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, facebook, messenger

I am setting up a webhook for Facebook Messenger API using NodeJS and Express. I have already uploaded it to a self-signed HTTPS server at https://122.2.53.34:8000/webhook.

I tried validating it but this error comes up:
[image]

This is my server code:

```js
app.get('/webhook', (request, response) => {
  const VERIFY_TOKEN = "facebook"

  const mode      = request.query['hub.mode']
  const token     = request.query['hub.verify_token']
  const challenge = request.query['hub.challenge']

  if(mode && token) {
    if(mode === 'subscribe' && token === VERIFY_TOKEN) {
      console.log('WEBHOOK_VERIFIED')
      response.status(200).send(challenge)
    } else {
      response.sendStatus(403)
    }
  }
})
```

I have also looked into [this similar StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36595183/facebook-messenger-api-trouble-setting-up-a-webhook), but it did not help.

Comment: You have `const VERIFY_TOKEN = "abc123"` in your code, but you are sending a verify token value `facebook`, according to your screenshot.

Comment: Plus, not sure if Facebook will accept a self-signed SSL certificate in this context. You can use a service like https://ngrok.com to set up a proper HTTPS tunnel to your local development machine.

Comment: I will look into ngrok.com. I've had a hunch that Facebook does accept self-signed SSL certificates, but I wasn't really sure. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling into this, you must ensure your response is a plain text message.

`res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');`